# Do special MySQL query optimizations work with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to optimize a query used in a PHP script, and I've been trying to figure out if PHP accepts [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) in SQL statements, but I haven't been able to find documentation on it anywhere.

This is what the format of the query is:

```
Select a.columnName, b.columnName from tableName as a FORCE
INDEX(indexName) Inner Join tableName as b 
On a.columnName = b.columnName
Where a.columnName =..
```

Please forgive omitting the actual query, as I'm more concerned with trying to figure out if PHP allows queries like this rather than the data itself. I had to add the forced index to my query to make the query perform faster as the initial table it pulls from is rather large. Can anyone help me with figuring this out or point in the direction of some documentation on it?

For those wondering, I've already looked at the documentation on the MySQL pages, so I'm not really sure what else to look at.

Comment: Donde esta "query hints"? ***YES*** PHP allows any query you can imagine.

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the results of your experiment?

Comment: @Dezza I have tried it and I saw no improvements in performance. So I don't know what other options I have besides the forced index

Comment: I think he means "table hints" ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Comment: Why would PHP put any restrictions on your SQL query? That query is sent to your database server, which will handle it.

Comment: In almost all cases SQL statements are send, as they are, to the database server. In this case you have to look in the MySQL documentation and ignore PHP.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken he means [Index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for clarification. was on the wrong track since it had the MS-SQL tag ealier

Comment: this is nothing to do with php

Comment: PHP doesn't care at all about the content of the SQL query. A query is just a string like many others and PHP sends it to the MySQL server as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, since PHP is just forwarding the SQL query direcly to the DBMS. So what works on the DBMS (e.g. MySql) will work with PHP.

e.g. with [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) for MySQL

Comment: Okay, I figured as much, but just thought I'd check. Guess I should try to see if it's something else causing the issue.

Comment: @AyeLetsGetCoding - If you're trying to optimize the query, why not take the coding out of the equation? Use something like MySQL Workbench and write the query directly in there. Then you can use "explain" to check the performance and modify it, if needed. When you got the best performance you can, just drop that query into PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have already done that, got the query performing really well, but some reason when I run the script it is still as slow as it was before optimizing the query. Maybe there are other queries I need to optimize as well.

Comment: @AyeLetsGetCoding Well, here is the "official" answer to your question. Please consider marking this as solution, so this question gets closed. And please feel free to post another question if you need help with further optimizing of your SQL queries. Ty.

Comment: @AyeLetsGetCoding - Or the performance issue is unrelated to your query. There are a ton of reasons why a PHP script can be slow.

Comment: @AyeLetsGetCoding If this answered your question, please consider marking it as solution. ty!